# Parse String to Object in Java

Tags: java, class, input

I created a project with 2 classes, Product and Stock. 
Now I created a third class "Menu" to interact with my 2 classes.

I'm using JOptionPane with the showInputDialog. 
I'd like to get the input to the type "Product" from my self created class.

I know there's a way to parse the input (String) to an Integer.

```
int keuze = Integer.parseInt(input);
```

So I'm searching an equivalent way to do this.

```
 private void addNewProductType()
   {
        String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Which product do you want to add?\n");
        stock.addNewProduct(input);

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really, no. If you look in the code for `Integer.parseInt()` you'll see that it does its own work in turning the string into an integer. You'll have to do your own: write a `parse()` method on your `Product` class that creates one from a `String`.

There are general purpose libraries that convert from JSON to objects, using reflection, but the `String` input needs to be in the right format, and this sounds rather heavyweight for your application.

Answer (score 0):

There is no default method to create an `Object` form a `string` because this operation varies from class to class. You must define this behavior yourself by parsing the String for the object's fields and assigning them.

For example, if you have a class `Product` like so:

```
class Product {
    String name;
    int id;

    public Product(String name, int id) {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

An `addNewProduct()` function would look like:

```
Product addNewProduct(String str) {
    String name;
    int id;

    // parse the String to get name and id
    // e.g. if str = "Ball 352", isolate "Ball" and "352" and
    // use parseInt() on "352" to get the id

    return new Product(name, id);

}
```